# issues with longtabu table splitting

Tags: longtable, tabu, longtabu

i'm trying to make a list of my publications (I know X here is overkill, just MWE), but can't find a way to make this table to split on 2+ pages, any hint?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{longtabu}{X}
    \hline Publications \\ \hline \endhead
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd ... \\
    \hline
  \end{longtabu}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Do you really need a long table?

Comment: @egreg Thanks ... Now I have 10 pubs and with X (text-wrap) it's almost a page (biomedical field, lots of co-authors) ...  i would say yes for the foreseeable future ...

Comment: A one column longtable is not a table at all. Use just normal paragraphs.

Comment: also don't put longtable or longtabu inside a `table` enviornment, `table` environments never split over a page.